# Build Error : LC : error LC0000: 'The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)'

Tags: visual-studio

I was getting this rather cryptic message on the build output in Visual Studio. There are no other errors but the build fails.

```
LC : error LC0000: 'The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was my licenses.licx file. I accidentally typed a few characters that causes the content to be invalid.

Comment: I'm using DevExpress controls, a GIT merge caused a problem with one of our license.licx files which in turn produced this error, I deleted the content of the license file then did a rebuild, this regenerated the license file and I was back in business. License.licx files don't need to be added to source control. Here's more information on the license.licx file: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T189453/about-licenses-licx-file

Comment: @Angrist Also had DevExpress issues. I tried a manual find-and-replace for a version upgrade, which broke everything. Looks like all I had to do was run the Project Converter.